# C defaulting issue

Tags: c

The title is vague, but I can't really think of how to describe this issue concisely. Here is my code:

```
#include <DigiUSB.h>

// Global
#define NUM_LEDS 2
int defaultReadings[] = {2,2};

void read_usb()
{
    int usbReadings[NUM_LEDS], i, numChars = 0;
    for (i=0;DigiUSB.available();i++)
    {
        usbReadings[i] = DigiUSB.read()-'0';
        numChars++;
    }

    for (i=0;i<numChars;i++)
    {
        if (usbReadings[i] == 0)
            // usbReadings is local, defaultReadings is global
            usbReadings[i] = defaultReadings[i];
        DigiUSB.write(usbReadings[i]+'0');
    }

    memcpy(defaultReadings,usbReadings,sizeof(defaultReadings));
}
```

So the defaultReadings variable is initialized to {2,2}. When available(), new characters are read into the local array usbReadings.

Next when the usbReadings are iterated through, if the usbReadings value is zero, the function should revert to it's old entry in that position. The size of usbReadings is ALWAYS the same as the size of defaultReadings.

However, this is not working in practice. The code runs fine and generates no errors, but it is not doing what I think it should.

Here is an example of what it reads and writes through four function calls to read_usb().

```
  Actual            Intended

Reads:  3,2       Reads:  3,2
Writes: 3,2       Writes: 3,2
Reads:  3,0       Reads:  3,0
Writes: 3,3       Writes: 3,2
Reads:  0,4       Reads:  0,4
Writes: 2,4       Writes: 3,4
Reads:  0,3       Reads:  0,3
Writes: 2,3       Writes: 3,3
```

As you can see in the last read/write row, it does work correctly sometimes. Is there anything you can see in my code that would give these weird values? I've been messing with this for hours and haven't come up with a reason for the strange behavior.

EDIT:

#### My Solution

For anyone trying anything remotely close, this may be helpful. Unfortunately this is pretty case specific, but I think the general solution can be abstracted by anyone truly interested in an answer.

Ultimately, I decided to put the "thinking" on the computer side. If you didn't gather from my comments or my post, this code goes on a DigiSpark Arduino-"mockoff" that is plugged into the computer via the usb port. It reads to and from the computer. Instead of having the DigiSpark parse for zeros and remember the last, I am having the computer do so.

Biggest reason in support of this is the DigiSpark's awful/non-existant debugging capabilities.

Comment: What is the size of `defaultReadings` and `usbReadings`?

Comment: What is the datatype of `usbReadings`?

Comment: I'll edit my post to answer both yours, sorry.

Comment: Did you say `defaultReadings` is always supposed to be [2,2]? In that case your `memcpy` is changing it every function call.

Comment: `'0'` gives ascii value of 0.

Comment: And you never read more than two values? In other words, `numChars` will never be larger than 2?

Comment: @zz3599 defaultReadings should change each time. I apologize for the naming, but it means the last reading. The name makes more sense in context.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes you are correct.

Comment: I guuess you reset `numChars` somewhere?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt yes every time the function is called. it is a local var

Comment: Definition of `available()`, please.

Comment: I think I get it, but your question would be clearer if you also stated what you expect the writes to be for your sample execution

Comment: @A.E.Drew Very good point. Give me a second.

Comment: usbReadings is an uninitialized array.  It can have data from previous iterations in it.  Have you checked that numChars actually is 2 each time?  Better yet, does initializing it change your results?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Good point, no I haven't. I will troubleshoot with that.

Comment: Needs an SSCCE, so voting to close. I'd bet that the process of producing an SSCCE will actually enlighten you to the problem.

Comment: @Roddy. It should compile if you have the library I include. I did not write the available, read, or write functions. If that doesn't help I'm not sure what else I can give. But maybe that makes it a better candidate to be closed.

Comment: @phileaton  - compiling is part of it, but you need an example that actually exhibits the problem. The code you've posted is "ok", except it is (and you are!) making  *lots* of assumptions about how your USB device and library are working, and the chances are that those assumptions - or something in your test methodology - is wrong.

Comment: @phileaton - your code has just magically changed to C++ . what's going on here?

Comment: @Roddy my primary purpose in bringing this up was to make sure that there was nothing blatant that I was missing. I.e. misuse of memcpy or something along those lines. I acknowledge that I am most likely making a subtler mistake but I was hoping otherwise by checking here. It is no doubt a faulty assumption I'm making. I'm also sorry about the C or C++ hassle. I honestly don't know. You'd certainly know better. I believe that the Arduino language is a subset of C but as you noted, the use of classes makes it... not pure C I guess? The DigiUSB library is definitely written in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read only one value in your first loop, the second value of `usbReadings` will remain undefined but nevertheless is copied to `defaultReadings`

Comment: happened to be posted simultanously to Scott Mermelstein's comment

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not complaining.  I'm just interested in the answer on this one.  :-)

Comment: @phileaton For the sake of testing, you may want to initialize `defaultReadings` to be something totally different (e.g. [9, 9]), and make your first test case be 3,0 (and then make the first case 0,3 and then 0,0).  I bet all 0 cases will work the first time through.